# expected number of cards that have been drawn at least once

Tags: probability

There is a 52-card deck, we shuffle the deck and pick a card (with replacement) n times.
What is the expected number of cards that have been drawn at least once?

I started to calculate it for specific n's, but find that it complex due to the dependancy of the previous results. I know that Linearity of Expectations should work in those cases as well, but intuitively it felt to me incorrect.

Comment: Linearity is good here, as you imagine.  Easy to compute the probability that a given card is never chosen, so subtracting from $1$ gives you the probability that the card is drawn at least once.  Then just multiply by the number of cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity of expectation is the way to go.  The probability that a given card has been drawn at least once is $$1-\left({51\over52}\right)^n$$ so the expected number that have been drawn at least once is $$52-{51^n\over 52^{n-1}}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate how did you get to the first statement?

Comment: @Bob_Bobb It's the complement of the probability that all $n$ cards were drawn from the other $51$.